# Print Batch Time in Milliseconds

Tags: windows, shell, time, batch-file

I am aware that one can print batch time up to the centisecond with `@echo %time%`. Is there a similar command to get milliseconds as well?

Comment: Is your batch file so fast that 10 milliseconds (5, on average) will make a difference ?

Comment: There's nothing built-in to the command shell to get the time to the millisecond, but powershell has the Get-Date command which returns an object that contains milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a resource kit utility named Timethis that provides up to the millisecond time measurements :

```
TimeThis :  Command Line :  dir
TimeThis :    Start Time :  Wed Oct 24 12:49:56 2012
TimeThis :      End Time :  Wed Oct 24 12:49:56 2012
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:00.093
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wmic os get LocalDateTime`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html). That's also the reliable way to get [locale-independent date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56165593/995714)

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%i in (
    `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE`
) do @set ctime=%%i
echo milliseconds: %ctime:~15,3%
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: doh, didn't notice that this has the windows tag. Leaving the answer here in case anyone else clicked on this for Linux)

If you are asking to time the execution length of a program or script, precede the command with `time`, for example:

```
time ls -R
```

and this will give you execution time in milliseconds:

```
real    0m0.667s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.144s
```

If you are asking for the current date and time:

Take a look at:

```
man date
```

For example,

```
date +"%X %N"
```

This will give you the current time in Hour:Minutes:Seconds and then the Nanoseconds

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Gnu `gdate` can make this very simple; try the code below in a batch file, for instance.  I use it to create unique filenames for batch processes invoked in command windows, and on my system under Windows 7 it's evident that, at least in a command window, two immediately successive uses of gdate never give identical results.

```
gdate +"%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S%%N"
gdate +"%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S%%N"

set i=
set T=
for /f %%i in ('gdate +%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S%%N') do set UniqueTime=%%i

echo %UniqueTime%
```

But I actually use something more like the line below, discarding the last five digits because for my purposes they never seem to matter: the preceding part is always unique.  This lets the unique file names be shorter.

```
gdate +"%%Y%%m%%d%%H%%M%%S%%N" | sed "s/.....$//"
```

Pretty obviously, the same expression works under Linux, so one can also use it there.

Answer (score 0):

ptime utility is "5ms or better" accurate

```
ptime echo hallo

ptime 1.0 for Win32, Freeware - http://www.pc-tools.net/
Copyright(C) 2002, Jem Berkes <jberkes@pc-tools.net>

===  echo hallo ===
hallo

Execution time: 0.022 s
```