# How to get Windows batch date stamp that is locale independent?

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

In a Windows batch file, is it possible to get the text of date in some location independent form to get the location independent date stamp as a string? To make the question clear... In the Czech Windows, the wanted code looks like this:

```
d:\>date /t
čt 16. 05. 2019

d:\>echo %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-8,2%%DATE:~-12,2%
20190516
```

However, in the English Windows the same code returns bad results for obvious reasons:

```
d:\>date /t
Thu 05/16/2019

d:\>echo %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-8,2%%DATE:~-12,2%
2019/1u
```

If the code is tuned for the English Windows, then it does not work in the Czech environment. How it should be implemented?

Comment: `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE` gives a raw date, you can manipulate it from there.

Comment: Yes, duplicate. Thanks for pointing it out. I did not see it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method you can manipulate the output of `wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    if ".%%i."==".LocalDateTime." set mydate=%%j
)
set mydate=%mydate:~0,4%/%mydate:~4,2%/%mydate:~6,2% %mydate:~8,2%:%mydate:~10,2%:%mydate:~12,6%
echo %mydate%
```

and in the specific format you seem to want it `YYYYMMDD` and excluding time:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    if ".%%i."==".LocalDateTime." set mydate=%%j
)
set mydate=%mydate:~0,4%%mydate:~4,2%%mydate:~6,2%
echo %mydate%
```